# I get a undefined reference in function main with code::blocks

Tags: c++, reference, undefined, codeblocks, forward-declaration

I'm using code::bloks with this simple project:

a.cpp :

```
int get() {return 0;}
```

main.cpp :

```
int get();

int main()
{
    int x = get();
    return 0;
}
```

at compile I get : undefined reference to 'get()' I can solve problem by adding `#include "a.cpp"` but this is not normal

I tried to include a header a.h with the forward declaration of function `get()` but get the same error message

Comment: Is `a.cpp` part of your project? Many IDEs won't build a file unless you add the file to your project. I have used Code::Blocks in the past but it was far too long ago for me to remember the specifics.

Comment: `main.cpp` doesn't need a *forward* reference; it needs and *external* reference.

Comment: [https://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php?topic=17402.0](https://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php?topic=17402.0)

Comment: @ScottHunter Do you mean `extern`? It's optional for functions. ("forward declaration", not reference).

Comment: You need to create a project and add both .cpp files to it. You probably don't have a project right now.

Comment: See [How to link multiple .cpp files in Code::Blocks for a single project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70689663/how-to-link-multiple-cpp-files-in-codeblocks-for-a-single-project) and [Code::Blocks - how to compile multiple source files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5971206/codeblocks-how-to-compile-multiple-source-files)